# Get radius of circle, when know height and width of part of including square

Tags: math, geometry

Know width and height of square's part, which include circle.
How I can get radius of that circle?[image]

UPDATE: How to get radius of LARGEST circle, part of which could be placed inside known rectangle

Comment: You don't have enough information.  The radius could be any size greater than half the height and it would work. Now if you required the circle to also touch the inside height at a single point... then you'd have sufficient information.

Comment: So, if required circle touch inside height at single point, how to get the radius?

Comment: Have you tried Pythagorean Theorem?

Comment: Circular Segment?  Just reverse the math.

Comment: There is the **_smallest_** circle that can be fitted into the rectangle and it is the one that touches the vertical side. It's radius is calculated by @ja72 (for natural cases when `2*width <= height`). There is **_no_** such **_largest_** circle, because as you increase the radius, the area of the segment gets smaller and the circle's arc becomes flatter and closer to the line. If you are really interested in the circle that gives the _largest area of the segment_, then this is surprisingly the smallest circle so use ja72's formula

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry / mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

```
R = width/2 + height^2/(8*width)
```

Find the correct triangle and the problem becomes trivial.

[image: sketch]

You have two equations.

```
height/2 = R*SIN(Φ)
R = width + R*COS(Φ)
```

that are solved for `R` and `Φ`.